# Find $\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

> Find
>   $$
> \int\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx
> $$

$x^4+x^2+1>0$, so not possible to factor, so I guess there is no direct way or through partial fraction decomposition. 
$$
\int\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\int\frac{(x^2-1)^2}{(x^2)^3-1}dx\\
$$

I have no clue of how to solve it, is there any substitution that I can give to $x$ so that it becomes simple ?

Comment: HINT: $x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2$ then use partial fraction decomposition

Comment: u mean, $\dfrac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}=\dfrac{x^2-1}{(x^2-x+1)(x^2+x+1)}=\dfrac{Ax+B}{x^2-x+1}+\dfrac{Cx+D}{x^2+x+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes exactly...,

Answer (score 2):

At  the bottom, write $ x^2 + 1/x^2 = (x + 1/x)^2 -2$. Then assume $ x+ 1/x = t$. Then you're done.

Let me right the detailed solution. Divide the numerator and denominator of the integrand by $x^2.$ Then we have $$ \frac{1-1/x^2}{(x+1/x)^2 - 1}$$. Then do the substitution business. Then just integrate the following nice cute function: $$ \frac{1}{t^2 -1}$$. After integrating, we have the following function $$ 1/2 ln|\frac{t-1}{t+1}|$$. QED